# Destroying a Postgres DB on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, destroy

I want to destroy the database but I'm not sure what the command would be. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to empty DB in heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820549/how-to-empty-db-in-heroku)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You shouldn't use a postgres command to fully delete your database, as you will not have permissions to create a new one. Instead you should use the heroku command to clear out your database:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL
```

Comment: What is DATABASE? I can't find the url. Im heroku there is only database name and host, user, pass. What is the database?

Comment: @siamii did it just now, the full command is `heroku pg: reset DATABASE_URL`, DATABASE_URL is an environ config and points to your db url, heroku knows how to read it, so just type it in exactly like that and it works.

Comment: If you already did do it the wrong way and lost permission to create a new database, how do you fix that?

Comment: A fine comment to protect folks from making a mistake, but not an answer to the question at all.

Comment: I would also recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906715/clearing-rails-app-database-on-heroku-production-site

heroku pg:reset DATABASE --confirm {app-name} is also a good command to use

Answer (score 34):

None of the answers above actually describe how to **destroy** a Heroku database, which was the original question (and what led me here seeking an answer).

From [their docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#removing-the-add-on), either of these will work:

- `heroku addons:destroy heroku-postgresql:tier` (where `tier` is the database tier, like `hobby-dev`)
- `heroku addons:destroy HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<COLOR>` (if you have more than one database of that tier)

Note that because this is a destructive action it will prompt you to confirm the action. If you want to use this in a script you can skip the prompt with something like this:

```
heroku addons:destroy HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<COLOR> --confirm <appname>
```

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Thanks @john-paul-ashenfelter for the edit suggestion. Not sure why your suggestions were rejected but I've made the changes you suggested.

Comment: To create the database again, heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:tier (where tier is the database tier, like hobby-dev). Have a look at the [reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases#1-provision-new-database)

Answer (score 9):

To answer Siamii's question above: `DATABASE` in `heroku pg:reset DATABASE` is by default `postgres`

Answer (score 7):

Simply follow the steps below. Run

`heroku pg:reset DATABASE`

to recreate the database with nothing in it, then run

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

to initialize the database with the correct schema & data.

Look at the new heroku documentation it helps ;)