# How to drop a single table in Heroku for Django app

Tags: django, heroku

I see how to drop your entire DB in heroku in Django ( [Destroying a Postgres DB on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622633/destroying-a-postgres-db-on-heroku-for-django)). However, I want to just drop a few tables (basically perform the sql commands in 'python manage.py sqlclear appname'). How do I do this?

Comment: I haven't used Heroku in a while, but shouldn't you be capable of getting DB CLI access? From there, you just have to execute the SQL.

Comment: Isn't [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) enough ?

Comment: i actually am having this problem because I messed up my South configuration..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hey this is pretty straight forward. You should just make a view function in which you can process raw SQL. I JUST did this yesterday trying to solve a postgres unique index syncing problem.

Views.py: Map this to some URL then visit the url in browser and the function will execute.

```
from django.db import connection, transaction

def dropTable(request):

 cursor = connection.cursor()

 cursor.execute(“DROP TABLE WHATEVER”) //custom raw SQL goes here

 success = simplejson.dumps({‘success’:’success’,}) //I do this as a success message

 return HttpResponse(success, mimetype=’application/json’) //you'll need an import or two for the json stuff to work
```

Comment: I think you should also add the statement for committing the changes to the DB in your answer above: `transaction.commit_unless_managed()`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I came across this post and I think there is an easier way to resolve this issue. Heroku rolled out [PostgreSQL Studio](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgstudio), a web based PSQL UI that allows you to view your DB and PSQL commands.

Once you've connected to your DB, just open a [worksheet](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgstudio#writing-sql-queries) and run

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;
```