# Is it possible to "shut down" my app's Heroku's Postgres to save money?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I understand that i am shut down dynos on heroku so that I don't have to pay anything.

I am just wondering if i can "shut down" my postgres so that I don't have to pay $50 every month for a database for an app which I will only fully launch in 3 months.

Comment: Potentially duplicate from this one: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622633/destroying-a-postgres-db-on-heroku][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622633/destroying-a-postgres-db-on-heroku

Answer (score 0):

Heroku Postgres does provide a 'free tier' database option that you can use when you're developing applications before they launch.

To use the 'free tier' database, you can provision the addon like you would any other:

```
$ heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql  # this is the free plan, by default
```

When your application is ready to go live, you can then backup your free database, provision a new, larger paid database, then import your data.

Heroku provides tools [and documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) to do all of this in a very straight-forward way.