# How to drop database in heroku clearDB?

Tags: heroku, cleardb

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7627780/900394) how to drop Heroku Postgres DataBase. But how can I drop the database if I'm using the addon [ClearDB](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb)?

Comment: I ended up deleting all rows by code from the server side (php)...

Answer (score 7):

**Other alternative**

Using the commands line:

```
heroku config | grep CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL
```

Result:

```
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL: mysql://xxx:xxxx@xxxxx/xxxxxx?reconnect=true
```

Pattern:

```
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL: mysql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST/DATABASE?reconnect=true
```

Replace to connect:

```
mysql --host=HOST --user=USER --password DATABASE --reconnect=true
```

Then digit the password and press enter:

```
Enter password:
```

Comment: where do I replace the mysql statement? Its not working in the console.
Also how do You "digit a password"?